# Why is my unittest failing with the error 'str' object has no attribute 'cursor'?

Tags: python, python-unittest, pymysql

I have the code:

```
def get_address_query(trader_id, connection):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql_address_data = "SELECT * FROM address where id = '%s' AND type = 'registered'"
    cursor.execute(sql_address_data, trader_id)
    address_query = cursor.fetchall()
    if address_query is None:
        raise Exception("address details do not exist")
    else:
        return address_query
```

and I have written the following test:

```
    @mock.patch('lambda_function.pymysql')
    def test_get_address_query(self, mock_database_connection):
        mock_record = (('test',),('first',),('last',))
        mock_database_connection.cursor.return_value.fetchall.return_value = mock_record
        result = lambda_function.get_address_query('test', 'connection')
        self.assertEqual(result, mock_record)
```

But I get to following error:

```
id = 'test', connection = 'connection'

    def get_address_query(id, connection):
>       cursor = connection.cursor()
E       AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cursor'

../lambda_function.py:92: AttributeError
```

I know the error is due to me not correctly mocking connection.cursor.fetchall but I am unsure on how to do it properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try fix line `result = lambda_function.get_address_query('test', 'connection')` with `result = lambda_function.get_address_query('test', mock_database_connection)`. But there maybe some more errors to fix after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed the string `'connection'` as the 2nd argument to `get_address_query()`.

```
lambda_function.get_address_query('test', 'connection')
```

Then within `get_address_query()`, it calls the method `.cursor()` using the 2nd argument `connection` (which is a string).

```
def get_address_query(trader_id, connection):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    ...
```

So this is like calling `'connection'.cursor()` which obviously will fail because [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) doesn't have such method.

Instead, what you need to do is pass the mock object `mock_database_connection` to the `connection` argument. That way, all calls to `connection` such as `connection.cursor()` will use the configured mocked object.

Here is the minimal test code that you might want to use as reference:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock


def get_address_query(trader_id, connection):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql_address_data = "SELECT * FROM address where id = '%s' AND type = 'registered'"
    cursor.execute(sql_address_data, trader_id)
    address_query = cursor.fetchall()
    if address_query is None:
        raise Exception("address details do not exist")
    else:
        return address_query


class TestSample(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get_address_query(self):
        mock_database_connection = mock.MagicMock()

        mock_record = (('test',),('first',),('last',))
        mock_database_connection.cursor.return_value.fetchall.return_value = mock_record

        result = get_address_query('test', mock_database_connection)

        self.assertEqual(result, (mock_record))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Output:

```
$ python3 test_src.py 
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
```

- Now, the response of `cursor.fetchall()` is as what we configured in the mock object `mock_database_connection`.